# Error 1918 during compilation with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I was getting below error while compiling a code base. Does anyone know about this error?

```
<Filename> : error #1918: out of resources (internal variable limit exceeded)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when the space for local variable in your function is too large.

As a solution you need to reduce the size or may be the number of variables on stack, may be by using malloc ie, by using dynamic allocation.